# flutter animation controller value not raise to upper bound

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to scale an image with animation controller.
so I make animation controller and call `.forward()` to animate.
but the controller's value stops before its upper bound.
The last value of `print("scalecontroller value: " + scaleController.value.toString());` was `scalecontroller value: 0.969156`.
I know default upper bound is 1.0 but `controller.value` does not return upper bound value.
How can I make animate controller to return value 1.0 at last?

=====EDIT=====
add codes for animation controller

```
AnimationController scaleController;
scaleController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
if (animate) {
          lastScale = _TouchScaleController.scale;
          scaleController.forward();
          scaleController.addListener(() {
            if(scaleController.isAnimating) {
              setState(() {
                print("scalecontroller value: " + scaleController.value.toString());
                _TouchScaleController.scale =
                    lastScale + ((initScale - lastScale) / (1.0 - 0.0)) * (scaleController.value - 0.0);
              });
            }
          });
        }
```

Comment: I'm using ```PhotoView``` library that already support scale adjustment with photoviewcontroller(the _TouchScaleController is photoviewcontroller). It works when I remove ```if(scaleController.isAnimating).```

Comment: @andromedian, When the animation controller's value gets to 1, `isAnimating` will no longer be true that's why you are getting the last value as `0.969156`